# Draw circles that are created as instances in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

So I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and I'm desperate for help. Please help me. I've got 3 classes:

Circle is just suppose to draw a circle in the frame created by Frame with random starting position (and defind the radius).

Frame is the mainclass with methods such as addCircle(), bounce(), start(), stop(), run() (moves the circles) and quit(). This class also creates the frame in which the circles are added to.

Interfa is just for now a inteface frame where I define the radius, number of circles and Frame size.

No matter what I try I cannot add more than two circle (one is colored and one is not):

**The "recursive way":**

```
 private static void addCircle(int n){
    Circle[] circles = new Circle[n+10];
    if (n > 0){
      circles[circleAdd] = new Circle();
      frame.add(circles[circleAdd]);
      circleAdd = circleAdd + 1;
      addCircle(n-1);
    }
  }
```

**Normal itterative way**

```
  private static void addCircles(int n){
  ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
  for(int i = 0; i<=n;i++){
  circles.add(new Circle());
  frame.add(circles.get(i)); 
  }
}
```

**This is how I create my Frame:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public Class Frame{

  private static JFrame frame;
  private static int circleAdd = 0;
  private static JPanel fra;

  public static void mainFrame(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    fra = new JPanel();
    frame.add(fra);
...
//addCircle and addCircles
...
public static void main..
  } 
}
```

**This is my circle:**

```
import java.awt.*;   
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Circle extends JPanel{
  private Random random = new Random();

  public void paint(Graphics g){

    int randX = random.nextInt(250)+50;
    int randY = random.nextInt(250)+50;
    g.drawOval(randX,randY,50,50);
    g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    g.fillOval(100,100,50,50);
  }

}
```

Comment: I  think you are using the wrong gui framework. You should switch to [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html) which is Swing's successor. You'll find [`Circle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Circle.html) classes there, and many classes to help you animate it around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that your general approach is wrong.  Instead of using a `JPanel` as the element, you should have a `JPanel` capable of painting any number of "circles". The `Graphics2D` API is capable of drawing complex shapes (including ovals).

The main issues I can see are:

- `JFrame` by default is using a `BorderLayout`, this only allows a single component to be placed in each of the five available positions
- Layout managers rely on the `preferred/minimum/maximumSize` hints to make determinations about the size of the components. They are also responsible for deciding on where the component should be placed. In your current implementation, this would mean that it's possible for you to paint beyond the visible range of the component
- Overriding `paint` is not recommend, and failing to call `super.paint` could cause a number of unexpected and difficult to diagnose issues
- Painting can occur at any time, so using random values in the `paint` method will cause the UI to constantly change

Instead, you could define your own `Circle` class which takes the location and size you want and simply acts as a container

```
public class Circle {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int radius;

    private Ellipse2D shape;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int radius) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;

        this.shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return shape.getBounds();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g2d.fill(shape);
    }
}
```

This is simply a container class, it represents the information need to generate the desired outcome.  It has a convince method which is capable of then painting the shape itself.

You would then need to create a `List` of these shapes and paint them to your component

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>(10);
    private Dimension size;

    public TestPane() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int maxX = 0;
        int maxY = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            int randX = random.nextInt(250) + 50;
            int randY = random.nextInt(250) + 50;
            circles.add(new Circle(randX, randY, 25));

            maxX = Math.max(maxX, randX + 50);
            maxY = Math.max(maxY, randY + 50);
        }
        size = new Dimension(maxX, maxY);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Circle circle : circles) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            circle.paint(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

One of the things you seem to lack understanding in is how painting actually works in Swing.

Start by having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

A deeper understanding of how layout managers and the component hierarchy work also wouldn't hurt